# Deformation problem

Tags: armature

I'm working on a project. My mesh comes from photogrammetry (3d scanning) and I want to make it move. My armature is pretty ok, but I have a big problem with the deformation that is being caused while bending (ex. elbows, knees etc).

I tried weighting by detail (polygon to polygon), so the movement only affects certain regions but there is still **big deformation** on my mesh.

So, is there anything else I can do to avoid this problem?

Comment: Meshes coming directly from 3D scanning are hardly adequate for end use, much less armature based animation. You should probably look into retopologizing.

Comment: is there a link (tutorial or smth) to start reading this?

Comment: There are many, you can [search](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=retopology)

Comment: Since you are going to re-topologize, do a search online for "edge flow" as well. Careful planning of your geometry will save you headaches when it comes to  rigging and deformation,